# Wiring ceiling light fixture with 4 wires

Tags: wiring

I previously had a fan installed here. There are 4 wires in the ceiling: red; white, black, and copper.
I don’t have a pic of the wiring going to the switch, but black wire connects to one switch and the red connects to the other switch. It is a regular on/off switch without a dimmer or anything

My new LED light fixture also has 4 wires: White (N); Silver (L); green ; and copper. I’m not sure what is the purpose of the green wire and whether it should be connected to Red or not? Can someone help me with how to go about this? Thank you!

[image: wiring from the ceiling]

[image: wiring from the new device]

Comment: Can you post photos of both the wiring in the ceiling box and at the lightswitch controlling this fixture please?

Comment: I don’t have a pic of the wiring going to the switch, but black wire connects to one switch and the red connects to the other switch.  It is a regular on/off switch without a dimmer or anything

Comment: Green, Green/Yellow, or Bare is _always_ a ground wire. DO NOT attach that to any hot wiring (Black, Red, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Choose either the black or red wire (cap the other) and connect that to the wire labeled “L” (line). Connect the white wire to the wire labeled “N” (neutral). Connect the green wire from the house to **both** the green and bare wire from the fixture.

It looks like the bare wire is the ground to the actual lamp while the bare wire is the ground to the canopy.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!!!